# How to make search button responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My website doesn't show correct because the search button is not responsive. If you want to see live here is the website

https://emeupci.com

I tried `col-md-4 col-lg-2` but it did not work.

Here is the HTML of my search button

```
  <div class="container-fluid headerimage" style="padding:0 !important">
                  <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0 !important;">
                      <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'users/img/map.png' %}" alt="map" width="1200" height="500">
                       <div class="dropdown col-md-4 col-lg-2"  style="position: absolute; top: 170px; left: 390px;">
                           <button  onclick="myFunction()"
                                    class="dropbtn btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle col-md-4 col-lg-2"
                                    style=" border: 26px solid #f9f9f9;
                                         cursor: pointer; 
                                         font-weight: bold; background-color: #447193;
                                         color: white; padding: 8px; border-radius: 0px;
                                         font-size: 16px;);">Search for a church
                           </button>
                       <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                           <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
                           {% for country in country %}
                            <a href="{% url 'users:cities' country.pk %}">{{country.country}}</a>
                           {% endfor %}
                      </div>
                      </div>
```

I want the button also shrink as I shrink the browser or as I open the site on mobile phone.

Comment: Unrelated: adding `a.social-icon:hover { text-decoration: none; }` will remove the small `_` that appears when you hover over your social icons at the bottom. Related: it looks like the absolute positioning on `.dropdown` (`style="position: absolute; top: 170px; left: 390px;"`) is what's messing up the layout. Removing that makes it better for responsiveness, but then you'll need to come up with a solution to position it vertically nicer. Could likely use flex to center it vertically (https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/ for more info)?

Comment: "I want the button also shrink as I shrink the browser" I also see some rules on the `button` such as `min-width: 390px` (not in your HTML, but being added in JS after page loads I think) which will prevent it from being smaller on mobile devices.  You could define different widths in CSS based on breakpoints for this button, or make the width a percentage.